# azure iis rewrite, baseUrl not rewritten

Tags: azure, iis, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

I've a url rewrite in my web.config on an azure app service to rewrite all requests for "www.example.com/*" to the subfolder "./test/*".

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/test/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Unfortunately the called url in my asp.net core site is `www.example.com/test/some-resource` instead of `www.example.com/some-resource`. This has some negative side effects.
Is there a way to change the baseUrl for my *asp.net core* application?

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition like below, `negate` true ensures it matches everything except base url.

```
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.example.com" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
```

For more details,  you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference).